# how to handle multiple parameters in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am allowing user to view books in two ways: either "list" view or by "grid" view.
so i thought to receive a parameter as grid or list and show the view page as parameter received. 
But i don't know how to handle this in controller of codeigniter.

And also i already have pagination on my page. My  url is showing `http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/viewallbooks/books/pgn/9`  and in this i want to pass a parameter like view=grid or view=list and i have to receive it in my controller.

so may be my url will be :
               `http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/viewallbooks/books/pgn/9/grid`
then how i will receive it in my controller.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: do you have both separate views ?

Comment: @GBD Please give some answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do it like the way you are getting the pagination number here `$page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;`

You could do this `$viewType = ($this->uri->segment(5)) ? $this->uri->segment(5) : 'list';` and if you want to pass it to the view `$data['viewType '] = $viewType;`

and then later in the part that you call the view `$this->load->view('commonfiles/booksview',$data);`, you could either have already created 2 separate views one for list and one for grid view and call the appropriate one depending on the `$viewType`or have both code in one view file and choose from there which to show with an `if` statement comparing the `$data['viewType']`. I recommend the first option.

Also in CodeIgniter you can pass the URI segments as function's parameters with the order they are in the URI, like this example `function books($hasPagination, $paginationNumber, $viewType = 'list'){` will get the parameters  from this URI `http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/viewallbooks/books/pgn/9/grid` and the values will be assigned like this:
`$hasPagination = 'pgn'; 
$paginationNumber = 9;
$viewType = 'grid';`

Also you can pass GET parameters as usual `viewallbooks/books?pagination=true&pgn=9&viewType=list` and then handle each one of them with the  built in function like this `$viewType = $this->input->get('viewType')`, `$pgn = $this->input->get('pgn')` etc.

Comment: you explained three ways to solve my above problem. So i thought to apply first one. I applied and tested but i am facing one problem. intially for first time if page loads then my url is `http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/viewallbooks/books/pgn/1/grid` but if i click on pagination numbers then my url get restarted to `http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/viewallbooks/books/pgn/1`  And because of this i am loosing my current views. what to do?