# url getting restarted when codeigniter pagination link is clicked

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have to display product info either in "grid" view or by list "view".

Intially i am passing a url like `http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/viewallbooks/books/pgn/1/grid`  but if i click on the pagination links then my url is getting restarted to `http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/viewallbooks/books/pgn/1` . Thus, because of this i am unable to load my view format data. 
How to fix this error?

This doubt is part of my friend problem [Browse the main problem link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642445/how-to-handle-multiple-parameters-in-codeigniter)

MyContoller.php

```
function books()
{
    $config = array();  
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'viewallbooks/books/pgn/';
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->Booksmodel->record_count_for_secondtopBooks('3');
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>'; 

       $this->pagination->initialize($config);
       $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;

    $data["query"] = $this->Subjectmodel->get_subjects();
    $data["query1"]=  $this->Editionmodel->get_edition(); 

    $data["query2"]=$this->Booksmodel->get_all_book_list_atHomeTop('3',$config["per_page"], $page);
     $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();


   //---------For getting view type and passing to the view to show data accordingly-----
    $viewType = ($this->uri->segment(5)) ? $this->uri->segment(5) : 'list';
    $data["vt"]=$viewType;
    // ----Ends here For getting view type and passing to the view to show data accordingly-----

   $this->load->view('commonfiles/booksview',$data);   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `base_url` to:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'viewallbooks/books/pgn/grid';
```

and change your URL structure to:

`http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/viewallbooks/books/pgn/grid/1`

The page number should be the last thing in the url.

Comment: and `uri_segment` needs to change 5 right? like `$config['uri_segment'] = 5;`

Comment: And again user can change the view type from the view page by clicking on the link [grid view link] or [list view link] . So again if user change to "list" view and clicks on the pagination button then view type should be the "list" view. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Yes, but you would need to modify the function header to include list type first, then page number. I don't see those in your function declaration.

Comment: where can i find `modify the function header`?

Comment: See here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri

Comment: i read the link page but could not understand how to modify the function header to solve my problem? Please help litle bit. I am struts2(Java) developer, First time doing php project.

Comment: function books($view_type, $page) , and then you would read that variable from inside the function. Makes sense?

Comment: You will likely want to set the `base_url` to `base_url().'viewallbooks/books/pgn/'.$this->uri->segment(4);` to dynamically use grid/list when it is supplied.

Comment: @Brendan Yes with this it solve my pegination problem. New doubt: if users click on the "grid" or "list" link from view page then how can i only change the `.../list/...` to `.../grid/...` ? i.e From `http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/viewallbooks/books/pgn/list/1` to `http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/viewallbooks/books/pgn/grid/1`

Comment: You can manually build the anchor by doing this: `echo anchor('viewallbooks/books/pgn/list/' . $this->uri->segment(5), 'List View');` and the opposite for "grid" view.